# Animate object and render last frame using python script

Tags: rendering, animation, physics

I have a scene where some bottles are falling into a tray. I need to create a python script that runs this animation and renders the last frame and saves it. I have been looking for a method to do it but I have been unable to find anything. I am only creating a dataset for another problem that i am trying to solve and this is the first time I am using blender and only for creating this dataset so I'm sorry if this is a very basic question.

Comment: The following links should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55637/what-is-the-python-script-to-set-the-current-frame
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122742/how-do-i-initiate-a-render-from-python-but-still-show-progress-bar-and-ui-update

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112029/is-there-any-way-to-export-the-last-frame-of-a-physics-simulation-from-command-l  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134521/problem-rendering-at-the-end-of-rigid-body-animation-with-script